# React - Inner-Object gets undefined as soon as passed as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an object-array. Each object has another object as attribute.
If I'm passing the object itself by prop the information gets passed but if I'm passing the inner-object only the information gets lost and it gets `undefined` und I can't read its values.

Here is my code:

```
const cards = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Example 01",
    description:
      "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo saepe harum delectus recusandae possimus officiis, eligendi praesentium dicta officia numquam at quidem doloribus sed odit fugiat deserunt iure? Cum vero exercitationem ea non aspernatur eos accusamus consequatur enim beatae, delectus laborum in illum eaque nesciunt nam cumque maiores debitis doloremque et fugiat labore voluptates tenetur at. Nesciunt, ea dignissimos! Sunt nihil deserunt, vitae id alias quidem iste accusamus. Doloribus, similique.",
    stats: { rating: 5, reviewCount: 30 },
  },
];

export default function List() {
  return (
    <div>
      {cards.map(
        (card) => (
          console.log("card in List:", card),
          console.log("stats in List:", card.stats),
          (<Card key={card.id} stats={cards.stats} card={card} />)
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function Card({ stats, card }) {
  console.log("card in Card: ", card);
  console.log("stats in Card: ", stats);
}
```

Output:

> card in List:  {id: 1, title: 'Example 01', description: 'Lorem, ipsum
> dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin…lias quidem iste accusamus.
> Doloribus, similique.', stats: {…}} description: "Lorem, ipsum..." id:
> 1 stats: {rating: 5, reviewCount: 30} title: "Example 01"
> [[Prototype]]: Object
>
> stats in List: {rating: 5, reviewCount: 30}
>
> card in Card:   {id: 1, title: 'Example 01', description: 'Lorem,
> ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicin…lias quidem iste
> accusamus. Doloribus, similique.', stats: {…}} description: "Lorem,
> ipsum..." id: 1 stats: {rating: 5, reviewCount: 30} title: "Example
> 01" [[Prototype]]: Object
>
> stats in Card:  undefined

And I also get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rating')

Why are you not able to pass inner-objects via props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map function defines a **'card'** argument, but you're using **'cards'** variable for your stats prop.

```
  export default function List() {
  return (
    <div>
      {cards.map(
        (card) => (
          console.log("card in List:", card),
          console.log("stats in List:", card.stats),
          (<Card key={card.id} stats={card.stats} card={card} />)
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor mistake in your code. It should be `card.stats` instead of `cards.stats`.

```
<Card key={card.id} stats={card.stats} card={card} />
```